# batch file Copy files with certain extensions from multiple directories into one directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt, xcopy, .doc

I'm a newbie, so bear with me...

I am trying to copy all `.doc` files that I have scattered throughout several subdirectories of one main directory into another directory using a batch file.  I have managed to get a `filelist.txt` of all the files (there are hundreds) out of these directories that I want to copy using:

`"C:\Main directory\sub directory"
dir /b /s *.doc > "C:\Main directory\sub directory\filelist.txt"`

What script would I use to xcopy those into one directory?  Can I use some code that actually grabs those file names from `filelist.txt` and xcopies them?

For reference, I looked at the question below because it looked like it was doing what I want to do, but it didn't work for me.

[Using xcopy to copy files from several directories to one directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585091/using-xcopy-to-copy-files-from-several-directories-to-one-directory)

Also, I would really like to understand this concept, so please break down the code for me to tell me what each item does, or at least include a link that will explain it.

Comment: Open the main directory in Windows Explorer, search for *.doc, select all (Ctrl+A) and copy/paste them to the new directory... I too initially went to cmd line for this, but the GUI solution is much quicker :)

Comment: I think you can just search *.doc and copy the results!

Comment: Use this answer to copy with subfolders https://stackoverflow.com/a/26421140/3197387

Comment: Use this answer to copy onli files https://stackoverflow.com/a/1224932/3197387

Answer (score 72):

In a batch file solution

```
for /R c:\source %%f in (*.xml) do copy %%f x:\destination\
```

The code works as such;

for each file `for` in directory `c:\source` and subdirectories `/R` that match pattern `(\*.xml)` put the file name in variable `%%f`, then for each file `do` copy file `copy %%f` to destination `x:\\destination\\`

Just tested it here on my Windows XP computer and it worked like a treat for me. But I typed it into command prompt so I used the single `%f` variable name version, as described in the linked question above.

Comment: How would you address the problem if the exe name has spaces in it?

Comment: @Euclid off the top of my head I'd change the final %%f to '%%f' to protect the spaces

Comment: Thank you so much. How would we do this while retaining the folders that it came from? Example: keep the files in their folder names and tree structure

Comment: You have to be careful about files with identical names in different sub-folders. You will only have a copy of one of them.

Comment: @user1456962 This can be done with a slightly more complicated script that saves the full path into a variable, replaces the characters in it with the new path, and then copies to the new path. Or, alternately, doing the recursion yourself using a batch file that calls itself and "hands in" the subdirectory currently being worked with.

Comment: @android-user Retaining the folders that files come from is the default behaviour of `xcopy /S` command. Paths will be relative to the `source` filepath argument you supply.

Comment: so I accidentally ran this code: "for /R c:\source %%f in (*.dta) do move %%f x:\destination", which rather than move all my stata files into a new folder called "destination" as I wanted has pushed them all into a single file, of ambiguous type, called "destination". Woops. Any idea how I can recover the original files?!

Answer (score 62):

Just use the XCOPY command with recursive option

```
xcopy c:\*.doc k:\mybackup /sy
```

/s will make it "recursive"

Comment: But if a file in is subfolder of  `c:` then it also copies the subfolder and the `.doc` file .... instead of the file itself without the subfolder

Comment: Glad to give you some extra rep for this.  I'd rather not script if there's a builtin that works well like this.

Answer (score 6):

Things like these are why I switched to Powershell. Try it out, it's fun:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.doc | % {
    Copy-Item $_.FullName -destination x:\destination
}
```

Comment: You can actually just do `gci -rec -inc *.doc | cp -dest X:\Destination` since `Copy-Item` accepts pipeline input. Also you can probably get rid of `Get-ChildItem` completely and just do `Copy-Item -Recurse -Include *.doc -Destination C:\Destination` since `Copy-Item` has `-Recurse` and `-Include` as well.

Comment: does this retain the subfolder structure? seems not

Comment: @Joey First suggestion worked, second asked "*Supply values for the following parameters:*". Tried moving Recurse to end, then started looking at `Get-Help Copy-Item -Detailed`, then decided I should just try your first suggestion. ;)

Comment: In order to move files one can modify Joey's solution like so
`gci -rec -inc *.doc | mv -dest X:\Destination`

Comment: what if I wanna include multiple different  different extensions? like png and jpg and gif?

Answer (score 4):

Brandon, short and sweet. Also flexible.

```
set dSource=C:\Main directory\sub directory
set dTarget=D:\Documents
set fType=*.doc
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b /s "%dSource%\%fType%"') do (
    copy /V "%%f" "%dTarget%\" 2>nul
)
```

Hope this helps.

I would add some checks after the copy (using '||') but i'm not sure how "copy /v" reacts when it encounters an error.

you may want to try this:

```
copy /V "%%f" "%dTarget%\" 2>nul|| echo En error occured copying "%%F".&& exit /b 1
```

As the copy line. let me know if you get something out of it (in no position to test a copy failure atm..)

Answer (score 1):

you can also use vbscript

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFolder = "c:\test"
strDestination = "c:\tmp\"
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolder)

Go(objFolder)

Sub Go(objDIR)
  If objDIR <> "\System Volume Information" Then
    For Each eFolder in objDIR.SubFolders       
        Go eFolder
    Next
    For Each strFile In objDIR.Files
        strFileName = strFile.Name
        strExtension = objFS.GetExtensionName(strFile)
        If strExtension = "doc" Then
            objFS.CopyFile strFile , strDestination & strFileName
        End If 
    Next    
  End If  
End Sub
```

save as mycopy.vbs and on command line

```
c:\test> cscript /nologo mycopy.vbs
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using this command:

```
for /r "C:\source" %f in (*.doc) do @copy "%f" "C:\destination"
```

you could also run these to make it simple

```
set source="C:\src"
set destination="C:\dest"
set extension=doc

for /r %source% %f in (*.%extension%) do @copy "%f" %destination%
```

In case you are willing to copy with file types parent folder name try using this command

```
xcopy "C:\src\*.doc" "C:\dest" /sy
```