# bat file to move all files in a dir and subdir to a new folder based on many extensions

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos

I was looking at this as reference: [batch file Copy files with certain extensions from multiple directories into one directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224880/batch-file-copy-files-with-certain-extensions-from-multiple-directories-into-one)

I have about 300k+ files contained in [sub]folders with many file types that need to be moved to folders based on their file extension. I need help forming the cmd to place files in respective folders based on extension.

Simi-Pseudo code:

```
for /R C:\Recovery %f.%EXT move %f C:\RecoverySorted\%EXT
```

The code above doesn't work properly of course. Need help revising.

If there could be error checks for non-extension files that would be great as well. I noticed a few files without extensions. Thanks!

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Echo OFF

Set "Folder=C:\windows"
Set "DestDir=C:\MySortedFiles"

FOR /R "%Folder%" %%# in ("*") DO (
    If not exist "%DestDir%\%%~x#" (MKDIR "%DestDir%\%%~x#")
    Echo [+] Moving: "%%~nx#"
    Move "%%#" "%DestDir%\%%~x#\" 1>NUL
)

Pause&Exit
```

Note: Don't use a last slash \ when typying the **DestDir** path.

Comment: This worked beautifully and in a little under 10 minutes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /s /b /a-d') DO (
 IF NOT "%%~xi"=="" MD "c:\destdir\%%~xi" 2>NUL
 ECHO MOVE "%%i" "c:\destdir\%%~xi"
)
```

Include your source directory name in the `dir` clause if you are not starting in the desired relative root. Change `destdir` to suit. The `2>nul` suppresses error messages on the make-directory because this will attempt to make the directory `.ext` many times. Add `>nul` to the `MOVE...` line to suppress the move-report. delete the `echo` on that line to actually perform the move rather than reporting the move to be made. Test on a small sub-tree first.

Comment: I'd prefer `for /R "C:\Recovery" %%i in (*) do ...` over a `dir`-based solution. Also I'd use `"%%~i"` instead of `"%%i"`, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Yes, I also prefer this form. `for /F ... in ('dir...` requires to execute a copy of cmd.exe and create a temporary file, whereas `for /R ... in (*)` is immediate and execute faster.

Comment: sure, filtering dir is not the way for 300k files.