# Batch file: Run command for every file of certain extension

Tags: python, batch-file

I run a python command

`python file.py inputfile.stl`

but I want to expand it to input several files at a time. How would I make a windows batch file that when ran, will run a command for every `*.stl` file in that directory. So for example it will run,

```
python file.py INPUTFILE1.stl
python file.py ANOTHERFILE.stl
python file.py BLAH.stl
....
```

Please note that the .stl files will have a different prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These topics can help: [Batch script loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591758/batch-script-loop) and [batch file Copy files with certain extensions from multiple directories into one directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224880/batch-file-copy-files-with-certain-extensions-from-multiple-directories-into-one)

So basically:

```
for %f in (*.stl) do python file.py %f
```

That will create a loop which executes all files in the directory with a .stl extension.

Comment: Not quite, the .stl files do not have the same name (prefix). So one of them can be called abc.stl while the other can be testing.stl

Comment: Ah ok, the question just changed :). When I looked it was still INPUTFILE1.stl, INPUTFILE2.stl, ...