# Move .X to parent folder (Windows)

Tags: windows, directory, parent, move

I have a specific structure wherein I need to move some files.

Example:

> C:\Root\Projects\Project1\Draft
>
> C:\Root\Projects\Project2\Draft

etc.

I want to move files of a specific type, in this case .pdf.

How would I go about scanning all "Draft" folders for .pdf files, and then moving them to the parent ProjectX folder and deleting the "Draft" folders?

I would prefer to have a .bat I could run for this, preferably running from C:\Root.

Being a novice, I assumed it was in the logic ballpark of:

```
Find files of type .pdf in folders named C:\Root\Projects\*\Draft
Move found files to ./ (parent)
Find folders in C:\Root\Projects\*\ named Draft
Delete found folders
```

However, I'm not exactly a wiz with commands.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: There's probably free software already written to do this. Try asking over at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. Otherwise, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224880/batch-file-copy-files-with-certain-extensions-from-multiple-directories-into-one#answer-1224932) might help.

Comment: Thank you, sadly my skills are not up to par here. I attempted **move /y "projects\*\draft\*.pdf" "..\"** but that didn't do it. Just gave me a filename/folder/disk name syntax error.