# Master batch file to scan multiple sub directories for specific file types then executing batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Please bear with me here as I am relatively new to batch files.

So far me and my colleague have created a batch file for all of our reports that need to be made and left them in the respective sub folders. What we are struggling with is creating a batch file in the main folder that will scan all of the sub folders(there are thousands) for a specific file type (for reference that file extension is .KI1) and if found it will run the batch file in that sub folder then continue on. I understand this is a massive project but the biggest issue we are currently facing is the function for searching all the sub folders for that file type we have the command for running the batch file.

I was trying to implement anything from: [batch file Copy files with certain extensions from multiple directories into one directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224880/batch-file-copy-files-with-certain-extensions-from-multiple-directories-into-one)

However I was unsuccessful.

Comment: In order for us to help you, you have to include the code you have an issue with, along with a specific question.

Comment: Simply use a `FOR /R` with `*.KI1`.