# Batch file to copy and rename files from multiple directories

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I have previously searched for an answer for my question, however nothing to this point has specifically answered it. See: [Using xcopy to copy files from several directories to one directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585091/using-xcopy-to-copy-files-from-several-directories-to-one-directory), and [Batch file to copy files from one folder to another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986447/batch-file-to-copy-files-from-one-folder-to-another-folder) .

Within one directory (`Data`) I have specifically named multiple directories e.g. (`SIAE02203`) that contain generically named .JPEG files (`plot.jpeg`). I hope to create a batch file that is able to go through each directory, locate, copy AND rename the `plot.jpeg` file with the parent's folder name.

So `plot.jpeg` becomes `SIAE02203-plot.jpeg`.

The structure of the directories looks like: `Data\SIAE02203\plots\plot.jpeg`.
I hope to copy the renamed file to `Data\Output`.

Would this be at all possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a short batch code for this task:

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\Temp\Data"
if not exist "Output\*" md Output
for /D %%D in (*) do (
    if /I not "%%D" == "Output" (
        for %%J in ("%%D\plots\*.jpeg") do (
            copy /B /Y "%%~fJ" "Output\%%D-%%~nxJ" >nul
        )
    )
)
popd
```

Specify in second line the path to directory `Data`.

The batch file creates first the directory `Output` if not already existing.

Next command **FOR** is used to process more commands on each subdirectory of directory `Data`. The subdirectory `Output` is skipped using an **IF** condition.

The inner **FOR** searches for each subdirectory found by outer **FOR** in subdirectory `plots` like `SIAE02203\plots` for `*.jpeg` files and copies all found JPEG files to directory `Output`.

The success message of command **COPY** is redirected to device **NUL** to suppress it.

Input example structure for directory `C:\Temp\Data`:

- **SIAE02203**

  - **plots**

    - **backup**

      - backup_plot.jpeg
    - image.jpg
    - *plot.jpeg*
  - **images**

    - image.jpg
    - plot.jpeg
  - photo.jpeg
- **TIAE03208**

  - **plots**

    - *another.jpeg*
    - ignored.jpg
    - *plot.jpeg*

Contents of `C:\Temp\Data` after batch execution:

- **Output**

  - *SIAE02203-plot.jpeg*
  - *TIAE03208-another.jpeg*
  - *TIAE03208-plot.jpeg*
- **SIAE02203**

  - **plots**

    - **backup**

      - backup_plot.jpeg
    - image.jpg
    - *plot.jpeg*
  - **images**

    - image.jpg
    - plot.jpeg
  - photo.jpeg
- **TIAE03208**

  - **plots**

    - *another.jpeg*
    - ignored.jpg
    - *plot.jpeg*

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`

See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `>nul`.

Comment: Thank you kindly @Mofi for your in depth and thoughtful response! I have over 1 thousand images to extract for a current research project and this is incredible!