# Batch file to copy and rename files from multiple subdirectories recursively

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-rename, batch-rename, file-copying

I have a lot of files in subdirectories, which i want to have

- in one folder without subdirectories
- renamed with the uppermost directory as prefix followed by its genuine file name.

E.g.:

dir1\dir2\dir3\fileA.abc --> Output\dir1-fileA.abc

dir4\dir5\fileB.def --> Output\dir4-fileB.def

I tried to adapt the solution given in
[Batch file to copy and rename files from multiple directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650536/batch-file-to-copy-and-rename-files-from-multiple-directories#38658281) for my purposes with the following code, but it is getting stuck in an endless loop as it seems.

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
pushd "C:\SomeDirectory"
if not exist "Output\*" md Output
for /D %%D in (*) do (
    if /I not "%%D" == "Output" (
        for /R %%J in ("*.*") do (
            copy /B /Y "%%~fJ" "Output\%%D-%%~nxJ" >nul
        )
    )
)

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though your Output directory is actually "inside" your source directory. Then when you are copying/moving files to Output - you are actually just increasing the number of input files that need to be processed.  Classic endless loop :-)

Comment: The Output folder is excluded by the if condition which works fine (in the reference solution, too).