# Recursively copy files to another folder and rename after source folder

Tags: batch-file

I found code here:[Windows batch file to copy and keep duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248393/windows-batch-file-to-copy-and-keep-duplicates)
and it's successfully copying all .csv files from their source folders to a separate folder created at the beginning of the code.  What I would like to do is not only copy the files but also rename them after the folder from where they were copied.  So:

```
Folder 1 
   xxx.csv
Folder 2
   yyy.csv
Folder 3
   zzz.csv
```

Should result in:

Folder called CSV_Files

```
Folder 1.csv
Folder 2.csv
Folder 3.csv
```

---

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set TESTFOLDER=CSV_Files
md "%TESTFOLDER%"

set /a counter=0
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('DIR /S /B /A-D .\*.csv') DO FOR /F "tokens=*" %%j IN ('DIR /B "%%i"') DO IF EXIST ".\%TESTFOLDER%\%%j" (
        set /a counter=!counter!+1
        echo folder: %TESTFOLDER%
        copy "%%i" ".\%TESTFOLDER%\%%j_!counter!"
    ) ELSE copy "%%i" ".\%TESTFOLDER%\%%j"
:eof
```

I tried variations of:

```
copy "%%i" ".\%TESTFOLDER%\%%~nxi"
```

to no avail.   Keep getting bad syntax error.  Any ideas?

Comment: I found a previously answered question that does what I need with minimum revisions.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650536/batch-file-to-copy-and-rename-files-from-multiple-directories